# Magento Upgrade from 2.2 to 2.4.5 - Big trouble with PHP version

Tags: magento2, updates

I spent 1 week trying to upgrade Magento from version 2.2 to 2.4.
In order to proceed I have downloaded and I am using composer 1.
My PHP version is 7.1 - Perfectly compatible with Magento 2.2.
With composer 1 I was able to get a "composer require" without errors.
I then launched the "composer update" command but it goes into error due to the lack of php 7.4 or higher.

Now: I could also update the php and finish the "composer update" but then the "magento/upgrade" will not work because it is the one of Magento 2.2 which only works with php 7.1

Do you have solutions?

I am aspects to upgrade Magento

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solution:

1, If you dont want to upgrade magento 2.2 to magento 2.4, you can remove php7.4 and use php7.1 again.

2, Upgrade magento version to 2.4.x:

- With magento <=2.4.3, you can use php7.4
- With magetno >=2.4.4, you can use php8.1

Step by step to upgrade magento version you can read it here [Upgrade magento version](https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-2-upgrade-command-line/)

Comment: I think I didn't explain my problem well.

I need to upgrade magento from 2.2 to 2.4

Now I use php 7.1

If I switch to php 7.4 the "magento upgrade" command won't work anymore because technically I'm still in magento 2.2

Comment: Try upgrade magento 2.2 to 2.4 first. After that, you can switch php version.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.4.4, the minimum requirement of PHP version is 8.1 so you need to make sure to change the PHP version then run the composer require to upgrade.

Check the official documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/release-notes-2-4-0-open-source.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-5.html

For upgrade process:

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-4-upgrade/

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Thanks

Comment: I think I didn't explain my problem well. I need to upgrade magento from 2.2 to 2.4 Now I use php 7.1 If I switch to php 7.4 the "magento upgrade" command won't work anymore because technically I'm still in magento 2.2

Comment: Hi @AntonioS. that's why you need to first check the prerequisite first and then migrate to Magento 2.4. Technically switch to PHP 8 or PHP 7.4 with version compatibility then proceed with migration as described.